# Form submission dismisses a parameter in my URL query string

Tags: php, javascript, forms, url, form-submit

I am building an web-app for a client and I am at a stage now where the first draft of the system is almost complete, however I have came face to face with a final problem that has put me way out of my comfort zone.

The page functions by using a GET request across three variables to filter data via an SQL query, these variables s,p and g are passed to the URL upon form submission to perform the search.  Everything works fine apart from whenever I try and toggle the sliders my ?s parameter is dropped from the URL which causes the query to break ( s is not getting submitted for some reason. ). The page in concern [can be seen here](http://ajsimsdesign.com/Kerr%20Pumps/wellservice.php?s=intermittent&p=15000&g=15000)

GET Variables & Query -

```
$pType = $_GET['s'];

$pVal = $_GET['p'];
$gVal = $_GET['g'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM pumps 
        WHERE pump_type='$pType'
        AND flow_psi <= '$pVal'
        AND flow_gpm <= '$gVal'
        AND high_psi <= '$pVal'
        AND high_gpm <= '$gVal'";
```

Form -

```
  <form id="pumpSlider" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?s=<?php echo $pType ?>&p=<?php echo $pVal ?>&g=<?php echo $gVal ?>" method="get" align="center">
       <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $pType == 'intermittent' ){ echo 'active '; } ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but1" name="s" value="intermittent">INTERMITTENT</button>
          <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $pType == 'continuous' ){ echo 'active '; } ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but4" name="s" value="continuous">CONTINUOUS</button>  
       </div>


      <div align="center" class="productSlider">
           <p class="inlineLabel">PSI</p><div class="filterSlider" id="psiSlider"></div>
           <p class="inlineLabel">GPM</p><div class="filterSlider" id="gpmSlider"></div>

           <input id="pS" type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo $pVal ?>" />
           <input id="gS" type="hidden" name="g" value="<?php echo $gVal ?>" />
      </div>
 </form>
```

Finally I used some basic javascript to handle the submission event of the form for when the sliders value changes.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#psiSlider" ).slider({
              // options
              start: function (event, ui) {
                  // code

                },
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  var curValue = ui.value || initialValueA;
                  var target = ui.handle || $('.ui-slider-handle');                                     
                  var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';
                  $(target).html(tooltip);


                  var valA = $('#psiSlider').slider("value");
                  document.getElementById('pS').value = valA;   
                  var valB = $('#gpmSlider').slider("value");
                  document.getElementById('gS').value = valB;                   

                },
                change: function(event, ui) {
                  var val = $('#pS').slider("value");
                  var val = $('#gS').slider("value");
                  $('#pumpSlider').submit();
                }
           });
        });
```

I am completely stumped for ideas, if anybody has any input I would be most appreciative, thank-you.

Comment: How about `?s=';delete%20from%20pumps;` ?

Comment: That's *an* idea (to delete the contents of `pumps`).

Comment: I honestly dont understand what ?s=';delete%20from%20pumps; would actually do?

Comment: It would make `$sql` start with `SELECT * FROM pumps WHERE pump_type=''; delete from pumps;`. Which would delete the contents of `pumps`.

Comment: Yes, and I wasn't answering your question, or i'd have done that in the Answers section below. I was pointing out that your web-facing application is insecure to the most basic of SQL-injection attacks, and that the surface area of your "comfort zone" needs re-evaluation.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm going to need to look into how I can go about getting around that, any pointers to sources I could maybe read?

Comment: For starters you could google `php prepared statement`, but I'd just stop development for 3 months and read everything I could about `web application security`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form has hidden inputs with the same names as the parameters in the `action` URL. Since the form uses `method="get"`, the input values are appended to the URL, so the URL has multiple parameters with the same name. PHP uses the last one, which is the value from the form, not the URL.

If you want to be able to distinguish between the form fields and the URL parameters, either give them different names, or use `method="post"`. In the latter case, you can retrieve the URL parameters with `$_GET` and the form inputs with `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barmar, I am still however confused as to how I would go about achieving a result.  What you've said makes sense and I can see why s is not passed to the URL, however I do not understand why a value for s is not passed to PHP upon the form being resubmitted.

Comment: After reading this over for a fifth time I finally found a solution, thank-you for your help!